# avoid xhr uploaded binary being automatically recoded by server

Tags: javascript, php, upload, xmlhttprequest

The upload client side has already forced the encoding as user-defined binary:

```
xhr.open("POST", API_PATH_UPLOAD);
xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined-binary");
console.log(binaryString.length); //Output 1455551, it's the original binary length.
xhr.send(binaryString);
```

But the server side is still receiving the content whose length is larger than the original binary file.

```
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
var_dump(strlen($content)); //Output 2063224, which is an incorrect length.
```

But if I use `btoa`, as a workaround, to textualise `binaryString` in the client side, and then send it, then PHP will receive the same base64 content as the data the client sent.

That means, if the uploaded content is binary, then it would be automatically recoded somehow. But I don't know what causes the problem. Hope someone can shed some light on the root of the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`text/plain` is not binary. If you're sending binary data, use an appropriate MIME type for binary data, such as `application/octet-stream` (more in [RFC2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt)).

Comment: I changed to "application/octet-stream" and "application/octet-stream; charset=x-user-defined-binary". The problem still remains.

Comment: @張俊芝 - `charset` makes no sense on a binary MIME type. See the updated answer, you're using the wrong PHP functions.

Comment: `file_get_contents` prefectly works with reading binary files. Problem resloved. It's caused by incorrect configuration of Nginx.

Comment: @張俊芝 - I don't do enough PHP to know whether you can use strings for binary data (I do see that the docs for `file_get_contents` say it's "binary safe"). Even with the updated configuration, you want to use the correct MIME type  so that all proxies between the client and the server know that the content is binary, not text.

Comment: "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined-binary" also works fine after reconfiguration of Nginx. But, yes I do agree with you that "application/octet-stream" makes more senses than "text/plain".

Comment: It did *in your test*. That's not the same thing as being robust across the various disparate segments of the internet. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Problem resloved. The culprit is the configuration of Nginx.

I commented out the configuration items in Nginx:

```
#source_charset utf-8;
#charset utf-8;
```

And then restarted Nginx.

Comment: That would appear to be *part* of the problem, but you also want to update the MIME type.